# Entity Framework 6: Associating a 'Child' Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Let's say I have a table that looks like so:

```
Person
{
   int Id,
   string Name,
   int? ParentId
}
```

In entity framework, I can add a new property `Person Parent` and I can tell entity framework how that should be mapped:

```
HasOptional(a => a.Parent).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
```

My question is, is there a way in this scenario to add this:

```
ICollection<Person> Children { get; set; }
```

Where the collection would be populated with all `Person` rows having a `ParentId` of this current `Person`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property for your children, like this:

```
public ICollection<Person> { get; set; }
```

Then configure the mapping like this:

```
HasMany(p => p.Children).WithOptional(p => p.Parent);
```

Then you simply have to access the `Children` property using lazy loading, eager loading (`Include(p => p.Children)` or explicit loading.

If you don't have the navigation property is still possible to do it, but less obvious.

```
MyContext.Person.Where(p => p.ParentId = parentId);
```

Comment: Are we missing something that ties that collection to the ParentId column?

Comment: This did it: HasMany(p => p.Children).WithOptional(p => p.Parent)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I wrote it by heart and forgot to include the lambda. In many cases the navigation property can be determined by covnentions, but in this case it wasn't possible, because it wasn't named "Persons".